# Moving one object data to another

Tags: java, queue

So basically, I want to move an object data to another object (Queue jockeying).

let's say I have

```
int counter1,counter2
```

and I have methods

```
void enQueue1(object data)
void enQueue2(object data)
void deQueue1()
void deQueue2()
```

And, for example, I do this

```
obj1.enQueue1("data 1")
obj2.enQueue2("data 2")
obj2.enQueue2("data 3")
obj2.enQueue2("data 4")
```

What I wanna do is when the difference between counter1 and counter2 is >1, I want to move the data from larger counter so I have a balanced counter1 and counter2

So, how can I move the "data 4" from obj2 to obj1?

I wrote a pseudocode that look like this:

```
if (counter1 - counter2) == -2
obj2.deQueue2
obj1.enQueue(obj2.enQueue("data 4"))
```

How can I achieve this in java code?
Your help is much appreciated

Thanks!

Comment: Why "-2"? Could you provide us with a simple example for counter1 and counter2 ?

Comment: Yeah, so basically I don't want the Queue between the 2 objects have a difference larger than 2. counter1 and counter2 are used to count the number of data inside both objects, so for example, object 1 has 3 data, so the counter1 variable will be 3. Anyway, I've solved it thanks to Berger's answer

Comment: like counter1 = 2 and counter2 = 4 ? what about counter1 = 2 and counter2 = 5? Or counter1 = 4 and counter2 = 2?

Comment: sorry, I forgot to edit the pseudo. Basically I have (counter1-counter2)<= -2 and (counter2-counter1)<=-2 . So it will automatically balanced both objects when we have difference larger than 2

Comment: thanks, I was really wondering about that ;)

Answer (score 1):

Have your `deQueue` methods return the last inserted object, and remove it from the current class as you probably already do :

```
Object deQueue()
```

Then

```
obj1.enQueue(obj2.deQueue());
```